# Postgres : Get multiple columns with group by

Tags: postgresql

**Table**

```
select * from hello;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | abc
  2 | xyz
  3 | abc
  4 | dfg
  5 | abc
(5 rows)
```

**Query**

```
select name,count(*) from hello where name in ('abc', 'dfg') group by name;

 name | count 

------+-------

 dfg  |     1
 abc  |     3
(2 rows)
```

In the above query, I am trying to get the count of the rows whose name is in the tuple. However, I want to get the `id` as well with the count of the names. Is there a way this can be achievable? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the "id" values, then you can use a window function:

```
select id, name, count(*) over(PARTITION BY name)
from hello 
where name in ('abc', 'dfg');
```

This will return the id values along with the count of rows per name.

Comment: `PARTITION BY name` will create a temporary internal table?

Comment: I'm not sure how Postgres handles it internally.  `PARTITION BY` just processes a specified group of rows (a window) and returns an output for that current row.

You're right, I forgot to take out the GROUP BY.

Comment: @wonder: no, it will not create a temporary table. It's different type of aggregation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I am getting it correctly, postgres fetches all the rows with the names given in the tuple and then performs a count for each of the ones which has same name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see all IDs for each name, you need to aggregate them:

```
select name, count(*), array_agg(id) as ids
from hello 
where name in ('abc', 'dfg') 
group by name;
```

This returns something like this:

```
name | count | ids    
-----+-------+--------
abc  |     3 | {1,3,5}
dfg  |     1 | {4}
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach as well.